# Square size with asymmetric circles grid openCV

Tags: opencv, size, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV for a project about my thesis, I have to calibrate my camera for a recostruction3D. I have a question about square size, I know it is the size of a square when we use chessboard pattern, but I use circles grid or asymmetric circles grid. Can you explain me the meaning of this term in theese case?

I thought that it hadn't influence and for the firsts set of a calibration didn't change that value fixing it to 50, but I try to change to curiosity and the results change. In particular way changes the closeness of *cx* and *cy* compared to ideal central point that I supposed in the center of image. If I put a big balue like 10000 for example, it's very very close, but I have a higher value of K2 (radial distorsion) and a similar Reprojection Error.

Someone can help me to understand the reason???

Answer (score 1):

For the asymmetric circle grid pattern, the square size is **half** the distance between circle centers on a row or column. Alternatively, you can think of it as, if I'm at the center of the circle at (row = i, col = j), what's the horizontal distance (in metric units like meters or millimeters) to the center of the next circle on row i+1.

I just verified this by doing doing a cv::stereoCalibrate() and then measuring the (approximate) spacing between my two lenses with a tape measure. I used the pattern by [Nerian](https://nerian.com/support/resources/patterns/) and confirmed what was printed is correct (i.e., for the US-letter pattern, the spacing is 2 cm, not 4 cm).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this myself. You probably figured this out, but for future reference - about the only logical measurement would be the distance between two dot centers in the same row - look at the pattern the algorithm actually measures as highlighted in color. The distances between two neighboring circles vary when you don't fix either the column or row, so it makes no sense to input that.

The algorithm basically sees the asymmetric circle grid as two separate, slightly shifted mesh graphs where the centers of the circles are the mesh vertices.

As for why we should worry about these parameters - as far as I understand calibration (and I am not claiming I am, it's been a long time since I have last done this) - the square size parameter doesn't affect the objective calibration itself, therefore leaving it on the default 1 value is perfectly fine for most use cases. What it does affect is the estimate of camera position / heading in the 3D space (extrinsic parameters), because the camera then uses the distance between the circles as means of calculating it's own position in real world units instead of a unit defined as 1 being the mesh edge size. This is only really useful for calibrating a stationary camera that is supposed to measure stuff or for stereo camera systems, not so much for undistortion purposes.

Comment: I need to understand the correct value of Square size, in some forum i found that is the half of distance between neighboor circles,in an other i found that it is twice. I know that it has a big influence about position of camera and for this reason i need the correct value, but i descover that it influences also intrinsic parameters and distorsion parameters. Initially i thought that it was dimensionless, but its influences about intrinsic parameteres let me think that it has a precise unit of measure, because i can't explain with other reason this dependence.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is actually half the distance between circles on any given row or column (see my detailed answer below).